# Deleting your profile from one community

Tags: support, user-accounts, community-user, network-profile

Is it possible to delete your profile from one community and stop being a member of it?

**I don't want to delete my full stackEchange account, just my profile in one community.**

I found this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/deleting-account but I'm scared to delete my profile completely.

Comment: are u sure that wouldn't delete my full account? i just wanna stop following one community

Comment: As long as you start from the site you want to remove your account from you should be fine.

Comment: @Wha2wear: I've done it. And so far I still have all my other accounts.

Comment: @NathanTuggy oh, thanks a lot, I'll do it then :)